# Function that returns a pointer to first whitespace character (isspace)

Tags: c, function, pointers, while-loop, char

I am trying to write a function that returns a pointer to the first whitespacecharacter in string s after pointer p, which points to one of the characters in s. If there isn't a whitespace character, it should return the null character \0.

Now the problem I'm having is that the solution I have to this problem doesn't seem like it should work. This is what the solution supposedly is:

```
char * FirstWhiteSpaceAfter(char *p)
{
    while(*p != '\0' && isspace(*p))
        p++;
    return p;
}
```

When looking at this what I see is that it would return the first character that ISN'T a whitespace, rather than the first whitespace. p will go to the next character as long as it is pointing to a whitespace, so by the time the while loop is over it will not be a whitespace and return that character.

Is the solution wrong or am I looking at it incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried running it on some sample inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right, it should be

```
char * FirstWhiteSpaceAfter(char *p)
{
    while(*p != '\0' && !isspace(*p))
        p++;
    return p;
}
```

here is a live example : http://ideone.com/k9upnQ don't mind the output code being in c++, the function in question should work in C in the exact same way.